# How do I retrieve only first element of each key?

Tags: javascript

```
$scope.data=[
  {
    "vpay": [
      {
        "count": 34
      },
      {
        "count": 21
      },
      {
        "count": 12
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "mastercard": [
      {
        "count": 0
      },
      {
        "count": 89
      },
      {
        "count": 9
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

How can I retreive only first entry of each vpay & mastercard i.e. count=34 & count= 0 & in the similar way second & third entry in an efficient way?

Comment: Which output format?

Comment: How many sub-object there could be in the first level object?

Comment: [
  
      {
        "count": 34
      },
      {
        "count": 110
      },
      {
        "count": 21
      }
    ];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate array and keys and add the values on the same index.

```js
var $scope = { data: [{ vpay: [{ count: 34 }, { count: 21 }, { count: 12 }] }, { mastercard: [{ count: 0 }, { count: 89 }, { count: 9 }] }] },
    result = $scope.data.reduce(function (r, o) {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            o[k].forEach(function (p, i) {
                r[i] = r[i] || {};
                Object.keys(p).forEach(function (l) {
                    r[i][l] = (r[i][l] || 0) + p[l];
                });                    
            });
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: How can I get the output as  
[ { "count": 34 }, { "count": 110 }, { "count": 21 } ]; i.e. sum of first, second & third entry of each key?

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = [];
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++){
 for(key in data[i]){
  results.push(data[i][key][0]);
 }
}
```

Comment: How can I get the output as [ { "count": 34 }, { "count": 110 }, { "count": 21 } ]; i.e. sum of first, second & third entry of each key?

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstElements = $scope.data.reduce(function(res, o) {
  return res.concat(Object.keys(o).map(function(k) {
    return o[k][0];
  }));
}, []);
```

Or using **arrow functions**:

```
var firstElements = $scope.data.reduce((res, o) => res.concat(Object.keys(o).map(k => o[k][0])), []);
```

**Working snippett:**

```js
var $scope = {};

$scope.data = [{"vpay":[{"count":34},{"count":21},{"count":12}]},{"mastercard":[{"count":0},{"count":89},{"count":9}]}];

var firstElements = $scope.data.reduce((res, o) => res.concat(Object.keys(o).map(k => o[k][0])), []);

console.log(firstElements);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by two methods

**Method 1:** Is the following:

```
Object.keys(data)[0];
```

and **Method 2:** Is the following:

```
for (o in obj) { ... }
```

Hope its helped you :).